# Centered block in IE9 and/or earlier version

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I can't fix an issue am having with centering a block of content in IE9.
I tried various stuff from the web, didn't work. If possible, I'd appreciate if this could be hosted somewhere where I can see it working.

I have defined doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        <![endif]-->
```

I tried adding this in head section also, before the commented "[if IE]" or even replaced "EmulateIE7" with "edge", didnt work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Firefox/Chrome:
[image: Firefox]

IE 9:
[image: IE9]

CSS:

```
.zone {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
}

.container {
    border: 4px solid #666;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}

.zone-label {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.layout {
    /*position: relative;*/
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.zone-green-949 {
    border-width: 120px 475px;
    border-color: black green;
}

.container-green-949 {
    width: 949px;
}

.zone-blue-308 {
    border-width: 76px 154px;
    border-color: black blue;
}

.container-blue-308 {
    width: 308px;
}

.zone-purple-629 {
    border-width: 159px 315px;
    border-color: black purple;
}

.container-purple-629 {
    width: 629px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="container container-green-949">
        <div class="zone zone-green-949">
            <span class="zone-label">Zone 12</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear">

    <div>
        <div class="container container-purple-629">
            <div class="zone zone-purple-629">
                <span class="zone-label">Slider</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container container-blue-308">
            <div class="zone zone-blue-308">
                <span class="zone-label">Zone 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div style="clear: right;">
        <div class="container container-blue-308">
            <div class="zone zone-blue-308">
                <span class="zone-label">Facebook Fan</span>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Answer is to add this (see Hashem Qolami's comment below): **-ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);**

Comment: This is pretty simple. To get [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to work in IE 9/10 you have to use the vendor prefix version of that property `-ms-transform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is to add this (see Hashem Qolami's comment): **-ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);**

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm unable to reproduce the effect, my guess would be that you need to set a transform origin:

```
.zone-label {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* Set the origin for different browsers */
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

This makes sure that all browsers use the middle as transform orientation point.

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: I've tried isolating the html and css mentioned in a separate file and applied the origin. Didn't work unfortunately.
When you said you were "unable to reproduce the effect" does that mean that it works fine for you? If so could I get a complete file where it works to check for differences?